# Number of functions from a set to another set

Tags: combinatorics, functions

We have two sets $A$ and $B$ . The first set has $m$ elements and the second set has $n$ elements . How many functions can we create using $A$ as domain and $B$ as range ? (with proof)

Comment: Have you tried a few examples? What about if $m = 1$? What about if $m = 2$? What about $m = n = 3$?

Comment: Yes , but I can't find any pattern.

Comment: If you choose $n=2$ and try a few (small) values for $m$ a pattern quickly emerges.

Comment: @chi I think it should be $n^m$ , but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can consider an example: let be $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$, we want to build all the functions from $A$ to $B$.

To each element of A (domain) is associated to an element of B (only one), while an element of B can be associated with multiple elements of A, so we have:

1. To the first element of $A$ we can associate one element of $B$ choosing it between three different ways $B=\{a,b,c\}$
2. To the second element of $A$ we can associate one element of $B$ choosing it between three different ways $B=\{a,b,c\}$...and so on

We can understand that we have $3^4$ functions. In general if we have $m$ elements in $A$ and $n$ elements in $B$, then we get $n^m$ functions.